# DELL latitude shows a blank screen unless connected to external monitor

Tags: laptop, external-display, display-driver

I have a DELL latitude E7440. If I power it on as is, a blank screen is displayed. However if i connect to an external monitor, it works fine. Is this a driver issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely this is a driver issue. To find out if it is a driver issue, load the computer with an external monitor (which works) and ensure the correct drivers are installed from the DELL website.

However, I would guess this issue is hardware related, either the screen itself is broken, or the cable between the screen and motherboard is faulty.